# Use of STATICFILES_DIRS in Django View

Tags: python, django, view, path

I'm using STATICFILES_DIRS in my view and it gives me the path in single quotes and surrounded by square brackets. How can I just get the path? For example, it gives me

['/.../static']

and I want

/.../static

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

STATICFILES_DIRS is a **List** more about lists you can read in official docs (see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

You can get the element of this list like this : `STATICFILES_DIRS[0]` when 0 is the position of a given element.

So I'm not sure if it's usual manipulate staticfiles_dirs in views. Read more about Django to do on the right way:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/